# Change div background acording to the selected category 

Tags: categories, functions, menus

I'm coding a graphic menu that consist in five divs with a background each. On mouseover the background changes and the child div disappears. On click, each one works like a link to the  correspondent category. I want to apply some changes to the clicked div, so I was wonder if there is some function in wordpress to get the selected category. So I can check for It and in function of wich category is selected apply the changes to the correspondent div.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without *actual code*, it will be nearly impossible for us to provide suggestions. (Note: please post the **PHP** code, *not* the parsed/output HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `wp_list_categories` (see [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)), it automatically adds the classes `cat-item`,`cat-item-{ID}` and (to the current category being viewed) `current-cat`. (It also adds `current-cat-parent` to the parent of the current category).

This should be enough to style any particular category a certain way, and style the current category a particlar way.

However, you can obtain the current category being viewed by, in your category template file, using:

```
$term = get_queried_object();
```

The current category's slug is given by `$term->slug`. This would allow you to add a certain styling to the current category (the exact details of how to do that would depend on how you were displaying the category links).

Comment: This was really helpfull. Thanks for your answer. I'm not using the wp_list_category, because I'm doing this menu from scratch using divs with background images so the get_queried_object() its going to be the more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the in_category condition.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category

With this you can check if something is in a certain category and execute script, and if it's in another category do something different.

```
<?php 
if ( in_category( 'category1' )) {
    // DO SOMETHING HERE
} elseif ( in_category( array( 'Tropical Birds', 'small-mammals' ) )) {
    // DO SOMETHING ELSE
} else {
   // DEFAULT ACTION IF NOT IN ANY SPECIFIED CATEGORY
}
?>
```

Comment: This will check if the current post is in a particular category. Thus it may return true for category terms other than the one being viewed because the post exists in both terms.

Comment: Good point Stephen. Didn't think of that.